# Pickle Load all of the .pkl files in the directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, pickle

I am making a Contact Book application in Python 3.3 for Windows 7. I am storing the contacts info in pickle files (.pkl). I want to load all the pkl files in the folder and load them with pickle and also display a directory of all the contacts with my GUI. Here is my code so far to load all pickle files in the folder:

```
for root, dirs, files, in os.walk("LIP Source Files/Contacts/Contact Book"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".pkl"):
           contacts = file
           print(contacts)
           opencontacts = open(os.getcwd() + "/LIP Source Files/Contacts/Contact Book/" + contacts, 'rb')
           loadedcontacts = pickle.load(contacts)
           print(loadedcontacts)
       else:
          lipgui.msgbox("No contacts found!")
```

Here's the code for lipgui.choicebox():

```
     def choicebox(msg="Pick something."
, title=" "
, choices=()
):
"""
Present the user with a list of choices.
return the choice that he selects.
return None if he cancels the selection selection.

@arg msg: the msg to be displayed.
@arg title: the window title
@arg choices: a list or tuple of the choices to be displayed
"""
if len(choices) == 0: choices = ["Program logic error - no choices were specified."]

global __choiceboxMultipleSelect
__choiceboxMultipleSelect = 0
return __choicebox(msg,title,choices)
```

Comment: Your post doesn't really contain any question. (At least i don't find any.) Please give some concrete information, what you want to know.

Comment: I simply want to know HOW to pickle.load all the pkl files in the folder and display them all individually in the GUI!

Comment: Unpickling is done (like you already pointed out in your comment) with `pickle.load` and showing it in your GUI depends on the library you're using for your GUI and can't be answered without more information.

Comment: How do I do it then? Is it possible?

Comment: What? The Unpickling or the Displaying? For the Unpickling: Just like you do. `loadedcontacts = pickle.load(contacts)`. Then `loadedcontacts` is your loaded, unpickled contact. And to the displaying I already said that this can't be answered here without more information.

Comment: What information? I'm getting an error: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes. I gave the CONTACTS read attributes by using open(file, 'wb') on both of the files.

Comment: The `w` means writing mode and the `b` means byte mode. You want byte-read mode. So your mode would be `'rb'`, where the `r` stands for read-mode. But you already use that mode mode in your example code in your question. So it should work just fine.

Comment: To know how you can display it we need to know what GUI library you're using, how your GUI is structured and how you want it to be displayed. Also if you have multiple questions it is better to ask them in multiple questions. In this case it would have been appropriate to ask one question for the Unpickling and another for the GUI.

Comment: I meant just to ask about the pickling. I think if I can get each individual contact pickled, I can figure out how to display it on the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question already does some stuff to load the contacts. The line `loadedcontacts = pickle.load(contacts)` is a good approach. But `pickle.load` expects an opened file rather than a file name. So instead of passing `contacts` you pass `opencontacts`.

You can save the contacts then in a list by creating a list before the outer loop:

```
allcontacts = [] # Creates an empty list
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("LIP Source Files/Contacts/Contact Book"):
    # Omitted
```

Then you append every contact you unpickle to that list:

```
            loadedcontacts = pickle.load(opencontacts)
            allcontacts.append(loadedcontacts)
```

And just as a side note: You should close the opened file when you don't need it anymore. In this example this means that you call `opencontacts.close()` after the call to `loadedcontacts = pickle.load(opencontacts)`.

Comment: Is there any way I could make a variable for each contact regardless of how many? I'm trying to figure out the GUI display now.

Comment: Updated the answer to show how to save all the contacts in a list.

Comment: Now that I have the list, how do I list each file as an entry? For example: I have this line to show the contacts in the list lipgui.choicebox("Select a contact to view:", choices=[allcontacts]) How do I format this so It displays each as an individual contact. Thanks for the edit by the way!

Comment: Right now, It simply shows one entry with the list.

Comment: That depends on the GUI library you're using. The documentation of the library could be a good place to start. Or you tell us what library you are using. (searching for "python lipgui" didn't give me relevant results.)

Comment: I just want to split the list into separate entries. The problem is, you never know how many pkl files there will be. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can obtain how many items are in the list (the "length" of the list) with the function len. example: `howmany = len(mylist)`

Comment: Thanks. How do I use this to create different variables or entries?

Comment: I can't tell you how you can create different entries, because I don't know which GUI library you are using. And creating variables for each item of a list is not really desirable. Instead you can access every element of the list with `mylist[n]`, where n is used as an index starting at 0. So to access the fifth element of a list you do `mylist[4]`.

Comment: Still not sure what to do! The way my GUI directory works is you give it the argument 'choices=' and list the choices. That will display all the contacts, but I don't know how many 'mylist[1]' ect. to put down even though I have the number of contacts (which will not always be the same).

Comment: How would you list the choices if you would have them as variables?

Comment: Like this: lipgui.choicebox("Contacts", choices=[var1, var2, var3]) ect.

Comment: Well, with that you're just creating a list containing the var1, var2 and var3. So doing `lipgui.choicebox("Contacts", choices=allcontacts)` should do what you want.

Comment: Alas, unfortunately this does not do what I want. Instead it displays one 'choicebox' with the first contact and nothing else. Then it displays a second choicebox with the second contact, and the second contact again on the same entry formatted as follows: {"Contact", "Contact.pkl"}! I have no idea what's going on!

Comment: Could you tell me what GUI library you are using?

Comment: I made the lipgui out of tkinter

Comment: Would you like to see the code for the choicebox function?

Comment: Yeah. Would be good. I guess this is a bug in the `choicebox` function and I guess doing `choicebox=[var1, var2, var3]` would result in exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: I actually tried choices=[var1, var2, var3] in a seperate program, and it worked fine. It may just be a problem with the contacts being in one list. Put the code for choicebox in my question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49608/discussion-between-ich-und-nicht-du-and-luke-dinkler)